# How can I make this inverse modulo program take in larger numbers?

Tags: c++

Heres the code:

```
int gcdExtended(int a, int b, int* x, int* y);
 
void modInverse(int A, int M)
{
    int x, y;
    int g = gcdExtended(A, M, &x, &y);
    if (g != 1)
        cout << "Inverse doesn't exist";
    else {
 
        
        int res = (x % M + M) % M;
        cout << "Modular multiplicative inverse is " << res;
    }
}
 

int gcdExtended(int a, int b, int* x, int* y)
{
 
    // Base Case
    if (a == 0) {
        *x = 0, *y = 1;
        return b;
    }
 
    // To store results of recursive call
    int x1, y1;
    int gcd = gcdExtended(b % a, a, &x1, &y1);
 
    
    *x = y1 - (b / a) * x1;
    *y = x1;
 
    return gcd;
}
```

I'm not sure how to take in bigger numbers like 15001 (mod 5729413260) without getting overflow. Should I not use recursion? I tried long long but that didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: "I tried `long long` but that didn't work" - What didn't work? If you consistently used `long long` for every type that is currently `int` here, and read numbers in properly, it would work just fine for numbers up to `2 ** 63 - 1` (make it `unsigned long long` and it can go to `2 ** 64 - 1`; that's `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`, far larger than the numbers you're discussing).

Answer (score 3):

You might change `int` to `long long`; if that's not sufficient, then `boost::multiprecision` might help.